# how to validate row in datagridview. if cell value is empty than should not go to another row

Tags: c#

[image]

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            DataGridViewCell Docnamecell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[0].Index];
            DataGridViewCell Gendercell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[1].Index];
            DataGridViewCell Addresscell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index];
            DataGridViewCell Contactnocell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[3].Index];
            DataGridViewCell Datecell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[4].Index];
            e.Cancel = !(IsDoc(Docnamecell) && IsGender(Gendercell) && IsAddress(Addresscell) && IsContactno(Contactnocell) && IsDate(Datecell));
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        private Boolean IsDoc(DataGridViewCell cell)
        {
            if (cell.Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Docname");
            }
            return false;
        }
        private Boolean IsGender(DataGridViewCell cell)
        {
            if (cell.Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Gender");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private Boolean IsAddress(DataGridViewCell cell)
        {
            if (cell.Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Address");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private Boolean IsContactno(DataGridViewCell cell)
        {
            if (cell.Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact no");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private Boolean IsDate(DataGridViewCell cell)
        {
            if (cell.Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Date");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have only posted the code , explain the problem rather than making it only title ,  ready rules for posting questions.

Comment: What is the problem?